# Figure set up at the exact position

Tags: graphics

I am working on Elsevier template with a single column format, I am unable to set the exact position of the figure. All figures comes at different position. So I want to put them at a precise place.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please, show us a minimal compilable example which demonstrates  the issue and how you're inserting the figures.

Comment: Plus for an article you should not place a figure "HERE" as it will probably not me typeset in the same way in the journal and thus is a waste of time from your side.

Comment: Are you submitting a paper to a journal? Then have a look at the author guide, you might be required to put all the figures at the very end anyway.